# Jenkins Job DSL trigger is deprecated

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using the Job DSL Jenkins plugin, and I have got a problem regarding the trigger. It is deprecated and when I update the code, then the deprecation warning is still shown.

Here the code before:

```
protected def job
 void nightly(String schedule='H 0 * * *') {
        job.triggers {
            cron(schedule)
        }
    }
```

Then the update according to: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Migration

```
void nightly(String schedule='H 0 * * *') {
        properties {
            pipelineTriggers {
                job.triggers {
                    cron(schedule)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

There is still a warning: Warning: `(JobBuilder.groovy, line 100) triggers is deprecated`

What am I doing wrong? Is the properties keyword wrong or should it be job.properties?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`job` basically represents `project` block of a job XML configuration file and its methods are converted to nested XML elements.

Your initial code

```
void nightly(String schedule = 'H 0 * * *') {
  job.triggers {
    cron(schedule)
  }
}
```

renders this part:

```
<triggers>
    <hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
        <spec>H 4 * * *</spec>
    </hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
</triggers>
```

Your updated code does effectively the same thing, because you are calling `triggers` method of `job` exactly like before the update. Another problem is that `cron` method specification for `pipelineTriggers` is different, so the correct code is:

```
void nightly(String schedule = 'H 0 * * *') {
  job.properties {
    pipelineTriggers {
      triggers {
        cron {
          spec(schedule)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can view available Jenkins DSL methods at https://your.jenkins.domain/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot, how does the command looks like if I have 'scm' instead of 'cron' in the trigger?
thanks in advance

Comment: @DRMTZ See https://YOUR.JENKINS.DOMAIN/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.triggers.TriggerContext.scm for `scm` method usage in `triggers` context. Jenkins DSL can vary depending on the particular Jenkins and installed plugin versions, so it's always best to check with the DSL API viewer on your Jenkins server.

Comment: thanks, that is what I´ve done so far, but I get still a compile error.
This is from DSL API Viewer:
`scm(String cronString) {
// Ignore changes notified by SCM post-commit hooks.
ignorePostCommitHooks(boolean ignorePostCommitHooks = true)
}`
Thats my current implementation, but it still throws a compile error, that should be correct or?

`void continuous(String schedule = 'H/5 * * * *') {
      job.properties {
        pipelineTriggers {
          triggers {
            scm(schedule)
          }
        }
      }
    }`

Comment: I don't think you can use `scm` method in `pipelineTriggers`. This page should show the available methods: `/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.properties.PropertiesContext.pipelineTriggers`